# Remote PowerShell, WinRM Failures: WinRM cannot complete the operation

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, winrm

When running `Enter-PSSession COMPUTERNAME` with `Enable-PSWSManCombinedTrace`, I see the following relevant messages in the Windows Remote Management Operational log:

---

> WSMan operation Get failed, error code 2150859046

---

> WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet.

---

> The WinRM protocol operation failed due to the following error: The metadata failed to be retrieved from the server, due to the following error: WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. .

---

And sometimes:

> The client got a timeout from the network layer (ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT)

---

`COMPUTERNAME` is a 2012 R2 Core server on the domain, under the same group policies as many other server for which Remote PowerShell, Server Manager, *et al* are working fine. I can RDP to this system, I can get WMI data from it (e.g. `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName COMPUTERNAME -Class Win32_OperatingSystem` returns what it should), and in every other way, it seems to be running just fine.

While it's set via Group Policy already, I've tried (numerous times an ways) to enable WinRM and Remote PowerShell, such as `Enable-PSRemoting`, or invoking the attendant steps this command executes individually.

I've changed to a different network interface, I've ensured other systems on the same network segment don't exhibit these symptoms, I've followed the advice of `Get-Help about_Remote_Troubleshooting`, and I've sacrified the requisite goat to Baal. Nothing helps.

These symptoms are reproducible from any domain client to this server, or if you contact the server by IP (after putting it in TrustedHosts). No other server exhibits this issue. There is no software or configuration (all the way down to FW rules enabled and features installed) that aren't on at least 2 other servers in my environment.

Any ideas?

---

**MOST RECENT FINDINGS:**

`netsh http show iplist` returns `127.0.0.1` on the non-working system, but returns nothing on the working systems.

As @out-null correctly pointed out in the comments, the fact that 5985 is listening on 127.0.0.1 is a problem. I've since excluded this system from the GPO configuring our WinRM settings and manually created the listener:

```
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP
```

However, the result in netstat is the same. Note the output of `winrm e` below, where the IP is listed as a listener.

Still stumped on this one...

---

**Original evidences/sanity checks**

```
$> winrm e winrm/config/listener
Listener [Source="GPO"]
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 10.11.10.117, 127.0.0.1, 169.254.34.30, 169.254.47.200, 169.254.236.165, ::1, fe80::5efe:10.115.63.10 7%16, fe80::5efe:169.254.34.30%45, fe80::28b8:be74:53c:2fc8%12, fe80::69a9:e404:12bd:63c0%15, fe80::7cf2:ec84:332f:221e%14, fe80::cdc6:5ca0:6ae2:eca5%13

$> netsh winhttp show proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:
    Direct access (no proxy server).

$> Get-NetFirewallRule WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP | fl *


Name                    : WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP
ID                      : WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP
Group                   : @FirewallAPI.dll,-30267
Platform                : {}
LSM                     : False
DisplayName             : Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)
Enabled                 : True
Profile                 : Domain, Private
Direction               : Inbound
Action                  : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy     : Block
PrimaryStatus           : OK
Status                  : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus       : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSourceType   : Local
Caption                 :
Description             : Inbound rule for Windows Remote Management via WS-Management. [TCP 5985]
ElementName             : @FirewallAPI.dll,-30253
InstanceID              : WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP
CommonName              :
PolicyKeywords          :
PolicyDecisionStrategy  : 2
PolicyRoles             :
ConditionListType       : 3
CreationClassName       : MSFT|FW|FirewallRule|WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP
ExecutionStrategy       : 2
Mandatory               :
PolicyRuleName          :
Priority                :
RuleUsage               :
SequencedActions        : 3
SystemCreationClassName :
SystemName              :
DisplayGroup            : Windows Remote Management
LocalOnlyMapping        : False
LooseSourceMapping      : False
Owner                   :
Platforms               : {}
PolicyStoreSource       : PersistentStore
Profiles                : 3
RuleGroup               : @FirewallAPI.dll,-30267
StatusCode              : 65536
PSComputerName          :
CimClass                : root/standardcimv2:MSFT_NetFirewallRule
CimInstanceProperties   : {Caption, Description, ElementName, InstanceID...}
CimSystemProperties     : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties

COMPUTERNAME$> netstat -anp tcp

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49174          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49178          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49191          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    10.11.10.117:135      192.168.5.71:64570    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.11.10.117:135      192.168.5.71:64571    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.11.10.117:135      192.168.5.71:64572    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.11.10.117:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    10.11.10.117:3389     10.1.1.2:57970     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.11.10.117:49153    10.1.1.2:58100     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.11.10.117:50601    192.168.5.111:8014     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.11.10.117:56508    192.168.5.177:445     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5985         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:47001        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    169.254.34.30:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING


SOME-WORKING-COMPUTER$> netstat -anp tcp

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5985           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49158          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49187          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49192          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49199          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49213          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.5.11:139     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.5.11:5985    10.1.1.2:58153     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:5985    10.1.1.2:58154     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:5985    10.1.1.2:58156     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:49203   192.168.5.177:49210   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:49213   192.168.5.177:52784   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:49213   192.168.5.177:54507   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:49213   192.168.5.177:59034   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52905   192.168.5.177:49210   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52906   192.168.5.177:49210   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52907   192.168.5.111:8014     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52910   192.168.5.177:49210   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52915   192.168.5.177:49210   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52918   192.168.5.177:49210   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52920   192.168.5.177:49210   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52922   192.168.5.177:49210   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52923   192.168.5.177:49210   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52924   192.168.5.177:49210   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52925   192.168.5.177:49210   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52926   192.168.5.177:49210   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:52927   192.168.5.177:49210   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:54938   192.168.6.8:49157     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:62632   192.168.5.177:49210   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.5.11:64307   192.168.6.8:389       ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Right off the top of my head, it matters that your desktop (or any other domain client) is running an up-to-date version of WinRM that is as recent as the one running on your 2012 r2 server (I believe winrm v. 3). also, have you opened the firewall ports on the server for remote listening?

Comment: Tried from Win 8.1 and Win 7, both of which have no issue talking to exactly same-configured other servers. The firewall is open - it has the same rules as all the other servers for which this is working.

Comment: I'd be tempted to look more from a networking perspective... Is the server listening on port 443? Other than that I might disable PSRemoting and enable it again in case some piece of the config was corrupted.

Comment: @TimFerrill, we've disabled and re-enabled multiple times. The WinRM listener is running; see the newly added data above.

Comment: Not sure if this is required ( I'm looking it up right now) but -according to your netstat on the server- you're only listening to your defined port 5895 on the loopback address.

Comment: @out-null Oh! Very good catch! That's a huge difference, and is almost certainly the issue. I'm going to see if I can determine why and change the listener appropriately. What's weird is that `winrm e` shows it should be listening on the LAN IP. **So now the new question: why is 5985 only listening on localhost?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it, helped by the evidence I recently added to the question:

> netsh http show iplist

```
IP addresses present in the IP listen list:
-------------------------------------------

127.0.0.1
```

On systems where this was working, that list was empty. This seemed rather counter-intuitive to me at first. Nevertheless, I gave this a go:

```
> netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1
```

Immediately after, I notice this output from `netstat`:

```
>netstat -anp tcp

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5985           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49175          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49179          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49190          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    10.115.63.107:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    10.115.63.107:3389     10.115.13.25:64873     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.115.63.107:49235    192.168.40.146:445     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.115.63.107:49291    192.168.40.45:8014     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    169.254.34.30:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

And indeed, WinRM works like it should.

I surmise, via testing, that if no HTTP listener is configured, then all HTTP listeners will bind to the default entity: `0.0.0.0`. Because a loopback address was configured as a listener address, the listener was binding to this address instead.

At some point, I must have taken some action that caused this configuration, though I'm not sure how. At any rate, it's working fine now. Thanks all.

Comment: There were a few technet articles that I saw that were related to this issue. The fix was the exact same as what you did, but the only explanation on why it happens was basically "sometimes it just happens". Basically, they suggest that in past times, this has happened not because of operator error, but it just *sometimes* happens. Nonetheless, cheers on getting this going!