# Problems with WinRM

Tags: powershell, winrm, windows-server-2022, prtg

I have a PRTG-Sensor that checks servers' Windows Updates Status. It gets automatically created with a template, normally it should work fine. We have 94 of these sensors running, and one won't work on a new Windows 2022 server, which is our new WSUS server. The sensor executes a PowerShell script and uses Windows Remote Management (Port 5985) for it. The server returns this error:

> Connecting to remote server failed with the following
> error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the
> specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over
> the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is
> enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM
> firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote
> computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the
> about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I've tried the following:

- Changed the network firewall's rule to explicitly open port 5985 on the target to the source
- `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted` and `Enable-PSRemoting` and `winrm quickconfig`
- Updated the Windows firewall-rule for WinRM (public rule listened only to Local subnet) as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60063137
- Checked if target system was listening to it's own IP (tried with and without) [Remote PowerShell, WinRM Failures: WinRM cannot complete the operation](https://serverfault.com/questions/666606/remote-powershell-winrm-failures-winrm-cannot-complete-the-operation?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- Changed WinRM GPOs [WinRM will not connect to remote computer in my Domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/1002098/winrm-will-not-connect-to-remote-computer-in-my-domain)
- `netstat -anp tcp` shows that tcp/5985 is listening
- Error in EventViewer says the following, which I'm pretty sure I did

> The WinRM service could not use the following listener to receive
> WS-Management requests.  The listener is enabled but the listener does
> not have an IP address configured.
>
> User Action  Check the underlying network configuration to determine
> if this listener has at least one valid IP. If the IP is valid, ensure
> that WinRM configuration does not exclude that IP address by using the
> following command:
>
> winrm get winrm/config/service
>
> Additional Data  Listener transport: HTTP
> Listener address: *

- Checked if the Registry had all values [The Server Manager WinRM plug-in might be corrupted or missing on W2K12R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/808879/the-server-manager-winrm-plug-in-might-be-corrupted-or-missing-on-w2k12r2)

I'm just really confused, because it should work fine without any configuration. Methinks something happened while configuring WSUS on the source system.

EDIT: Here's some helpful command outputs:

[command output of win get winrm/config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5CIC.png)

[command output of winrm get wmicimv2/Win32_Service?Name=WinRM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKEq0.png)

What's really weird aswell that I forgot to mention is that all the other sensors on the machine work.

Comment: A *lot* of Microsoft components use WinRM. If WinRM is non-functional on a new system something is really wrong. Have you tried running any WinRM or winrs commands?

Comment: @GregAskew I added some command outputs. I also tried `winrrm quickconfig` and it said "WinRM service is already running on this machine. WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer."

Comment: A possible problem that comes to mind is the following: The sensor's description says the following: "The Windows Updates Status (PowerShell) sensor monitors the status of Windows updates on a computer and counts the available and installed Windows updates that are either from Microsoft **or from the local Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) server**."  Maybe because it gets the information from the WSUS server, which is the machine itself, there's some problem that could appear?

Comment: Being unable to perform a winrm id ping remotely is unrelated to Windows Update or WSUS. That's a fundamental connectivity issue.